# "a house to live in" vs. "a place to live"

Tags: to-infinitive

1. "They need *a house* **to live *in***." In this sentence, you can't omit "in", right?
   But
2. "They need *a place* **to live**." In this sentence, you can omit "in", right?

Why is that? any rule, here?

Comment: This could be because one does not need a house to survive (or to live), but they do need a place where they can live. But if they need a house, then they need to live in the house, whereas one does not need to live in (within) a place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual with these sentences just plucked at random and used as examples it is difficult to answer because I do not know what you are thinking.

---

**"They need a house to live in."**  means they need a "House" where they can live and it is generally accepted that you live inside a house. This sentence would pertain to **a person, a family or a group of people**. It is also specific that **they are going to live in this house.**

---

**"They need a house to live.**" would not be correct as they are able to live without a house. **"They need a house."** is not specific as you do not know if they will live there or rent it.

---

Q. **"They need a place to live**." *In this sentence, you can omit "in", right? Why is that? any rule, here?"*

**Firstly the meaning is not the same** as ***"They need a house to live in."*** or "**They need a place to live in."**

"**A place to live**". could pertain to **a person, a family or a group of people**. However it could equally be used with a herd of elephants or a pack of wolves. It could relate to an area or a home. **It is not specific** it is just a general statement.

When you say "**They need a place to live in."** it implies that you are using place to mean house/apartment or some sort of structure to **"live inside"**. With this use we now know they need some kind of property but what type has not been specified.

**Therefore there is no rule**, as firstly the two sentences (if both have "in" at the end) have slightly different meanings and secondly, the meaning of live is significantly different to "live in" when used in this context.

All ref CED [In](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in) [Place](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/place)

Comment: Ah ha! I got it! Thank you for your detailed answer:)